# How to properly install Python and Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to set up a Python/Django dev environment on my LinuxMint 19.1 machine. I installed the newest version of Python 3.7.3, Pip and Django.  It seemed to be working until I figured out it was not using the correct version of Python.  All attempts to correct this have been difficult.

When I typed `python -V` it would display Python 2.x. When I typed `python3 -V` it would display Python 3.6.8. So I updated the alternatives and configured python so now when I type `python -V` I get Python 3.7.3 and when I type python3 -V I still get Python 3.6.8.  I saw that I had to reinstall Django for it to be associated with the new version of Python so I tried to install again using Pip but got an error (the same ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' error as below).  So I uninstalled Pip and reinstall it.  I went ahead and installed Pip.

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

This reported that it worked fine.  I then tried to install Django and got the same error again.

```
pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

So now I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm not sure if I did something wrong to create this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Setup Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment) from Mozilla worked well for me.  [The Virtual Env Section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment#Using_Django_inside_a_Python_virtual_environment) is a great way to go. A key benefit of virtual envs is resolving the version management pain you are experiencing.

Comment: @gtonn, I have added an answer to your question. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check whether you can access to [Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/) shell by running `python3.7` command. You will see something like this.

[image: Python 3.7 shell]

If it's working, don't worry. Few more steps to go. Then install or upgrade your `pip` on [Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/). Run `python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip` command.

[image: install or upgrade pip for Python 3.7]

You can install any `pip` package in this way. `python3.7 -m pip install Django`.

[image: installing Django for Python 3.7]

I got the permission error, so I ran it with `sudo` privileges.

```sh
python3.7 manage.py makemigrations
python3.7 manage.py migrate
python3.7 manage.py runserver

python3.7 manage.py <your_command>
```

In this way you can run your Django project which you created for [Python 3.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370/).

Answer (score 1):

`python-pip3` is for `python3`

After you've installed package `python-pip3` you'll need to run `pip3 install xxxx` correspondingly.

All of the above is not related to the alternatives though.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.x comes with Linux system. just use pip3 install django

Comment: i had same issue with mac which comes with python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `pipenv install django` or `poetry add django` as that comes with virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your problem is because on Linux, pip is used for python2 and pip3 is for python3. Refer to this [article](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/) for step by step instructions on installing pip3 or pip on Linux.

It also sounds like you are struggling to manage your python versions, so I would recommend using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

For mac, this is how I set up my laptop (note minor version subject to change).

#### execute in terminal

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.7.1
pyenv install 3.6.6
pyenv install 2.7.15
pyenv global 3.7.1 3.6.6 2.7.15
```

#### Add to bash profile:

```
#pyenv
PATH="$(pyenv root)/shims:${PATH}"
export PATH
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

For further details on managing the pip packages that you install, see [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/). Since you will want to know what version of django and other dependencies are installed and be able to easily update once you have your project underway. If you go this route, you will eliminate these issues since the install would then be `pipenv isntall django` instead of `pip3 install django`.

Answer (score 0):

According to you, you have installed Python 3 (3.7.3), and `pip` comes [already installed](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) since Python 3 > 3.4. In addition, you are saying that you have set your machine so when you run `python -V`, you get 3.7.3. You can install `django` by running the following command:

```
$ python -m pip install django
```

However, the recommended way to install a package is to create a [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/#why-the-need-for-virtual-environments). Then, you can follow up the next steps:

```
$ python -m venv venv # this will create a virtual environment called venv
$ source venv/bin/activate # activates your virtual environment 
$ pip install django # installs django in your virtual environment
```

This will install `django` in a virtual environment. Notice that you will have an indicator that you are using a virtual environment in your terminal. `(venv) $`